# Run as admin inside HTA app for JS function

Tags: javascript, function, hta, runas

so I have made the following function for my HTA application that deletes some folders, downloads a new one and creates a shortcut on the desktop. It works fine, the problem occurs when I try to add Run as admin function, to execute following commands as administrator.

This is run as admin code which I took from my batch file:

```
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)
```

I tried to add the following code to my function, at the top:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Run() {
var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
WShell.Run('cmd /c if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)', 0, true);


WShell.Run('cmd /c PING localhost -n 5 >NUL', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c start mshta.exe "\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\programayendebaWAIT.hta"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c PING localhost -n 1 >NUL', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM CustomDeclaration.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM Nasamartleoba.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM Aqti.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM customDeclaration.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM nasamartleoba.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM aqti.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM customdeclaration.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c PING localhost -n 1 >NUL', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM Nasamartleoba /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM Aqtebi /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM aqtebi /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM aqtebi.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM Aqtebi.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM CustomDeclaration /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM Aqti /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM CustomDeclarationUpdate.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM CustomDeclaration.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM CustomDeclaration.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM CustomDeclaration.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c taskkill /F /IM CustomDeclaration.exe /T', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c PING localhost -n 1 >NUL', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c RD /S /Q "C:\\saagento\\CustomDeclaration"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c RD /S /Q "C:\\saagento\\Custom Declaration"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c RD /S /Q "C:\\CustomDeclaration"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c RD /S /Q "C:\\Custom Declaration"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c PING localhost -n 3 >NUL', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c xcopy "\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\saagento prog\\CustomDeclaration" "C:\\saagento\\CustomDeclaration" /E /I /S /Y /D', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c xcopy "\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\CustomDeclarationUpdate.exe - V.lnk" "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop" /y', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclarationUpdate.exe - Shortcut.lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclarationUpdate.exe - Shortcut (2).lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclarationUpdate - Shortcut.lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclarationUpdate - Shortcut (2).lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclaration.exe - Shortcut.lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclaration.exe - Shortcut (2).lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclaration - Shortcut.lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c del /f "%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\CustomDeclaration - Shortcut (2).lnk"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c start "" "\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\killlaProgramayendebawait.vbs"', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep', 0, true);
}

</script>
```

But for some reason it won't work, it works if you will execute it via bat file, but if you try to execute it from HTA application it gives following error: Expected')'.

I think you should use some special characters around ()?

Comment: You've messed with quoting, escape the the single quotes around `%0`.

Comment: I am newbie, sorry. How do you escape the the single quotes in this case?

Comment: In JS, the backslash (`\ `) is the escape character, i.e. you do `\'%0\'`, or use double quotes if allowed.

Comment: It fixed above listed error, but for some reason, it won't prompt window that asks for admin's username and password. It just skips first part of the code (the one which asks for administrator credentials) and continues to execute rest of the code as normal user.

Is there any other way to execute listed function as administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't take into account that the batch doesn't strip the incoming quotes.

From the batch file, taking into account the need to remove quotes %0, and the call will be

```
    set p=%0                                                                                    
    set p=!p:"=!
    SET code=""""start -verb runas '%p%'""""
    mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Run ""powershell -noexit -command %code%"",0,false:close")
```

If you need only trust level then

```
    :: 0x40000  Admin 0x20000 - User
    runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypas -command Some-Command-Line"
```